# Why is rectified open circuit voltage much lower than with a load?

Tags: transformer

I rewound the secondary of a 850 watt microwave oven transformer (MOT) so the open circuit voltage (OCV) after rectified by a full bridge rectifier is 14.4 volts. The laminations are not shorted. When I hook the output up to a 12 volt lead acid battery, suddenly the voltage jumps to about 17-18 volts. This is very frustrating. When I hookup a 25 watt 12 volt car battery to the rectified output,  the light works great and the voltage is about 12.9 which would be expected. So for resistive loads everything is fine (assuming battery is not resistive load).  Can someone please tell me whats happening here? Thank you very much in advance.-Kurt

Edit Addition:
I guess my main issue is that the open circuit voltage is LOWER than the voltage with a load, but only when connected to a battery. All other resistive and inductive loads, the voltage drops as expected.

Comment: Do you have a smoothing cap? How are you taking these measurements? Are you measuring Peak/RMS/?? What is the difference between your "12 volt lead acid battery" and "25 watt 12 volt car battery", since every car battery I've seen is a lead-acid. What state of charge are these 2 batteries at?

Comment: Way too much hand waving and inconsistent description.  When you connect a 12 V battery, one thing happens.  Then when you connect a 12 V battery, another thing happens.  No schematic is shown, and you haven't mentioned the size of the cap, if any, on the output.

Comment: I think one of your batteries is a lightbulb. This is just a wild guess. What you're measuring voltage with, I can't imagine, but I suspect you are about to learn the difference between peak, average and RMS voltages, and regulation under load. And you might want to mention what you want to use this modified transformer for.

Comment: Have you in fact left your meter on an AC range when you should be using a DC range?

Comment: I do not have a smoothing cap. It is a full bridge rectifier from an old computer power supply. I am taking the measurements with a cheap multimeter. I know the difference between peak, average, and RMS. It is my understanding that my multimeter measures RMS when measuring AC. However, all the measurments I am talking about I am measuring using DC setting. Edit... I didn't mean to say 25 watt 12 volt car BATTERY, meant to say light. Sorry. I hooked it up to an inductive load as well and works just fine. I want to use the transformer to charge a car battery. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I rewound the secondary of a 850 watt microwave oven transformer (MOT)
>   so the open circuit voltage (OCV) after rectified by a full bridge
>   rectifier is 14.4 volts.

OK, that's a peak voltage of about 22.6 volts: -

[image]

Your meter reads the average voltage (when set to DC) and that is 0.636 times the peak voltage.

When a moderate load is applied, that peak voltage will drop to about 21.2 volts. This drop is due to the forward volt drop of the diodes in the bridge rectifier.

So you connect this to a 12V lead-acid battery and you need to take care here because you are exceeding the charge voltage limits (usully about 15 volts for a deep charge). But ignoring your ignorance and assuming that you only did this for a few seconds to take your reading, it should not be surprising what is happening.

Your original reading was 14.4 volts and now, with the battery it reads 17 or 18 volts - this is because there can be no voltage returning to zero volts in the rectified waveform - it returns to maybe 13 volts (i.e. the car battery voltage) so now your average reading is somewhere between 13 volts and 21 volts. That sounds about right if you read 17 volts.

Be very careful about what you are doing here - do not leave the 12V battery connected to this output - it is dangerous.

Comment: Most of what you said makes sense to me. I think, using your explanation, I can see why the reading would be higher when connected to a battery. Since newerish multimeters are such high impedance, the diodes in the rectifier don't block the current going the other way since its well below blocking current from the datasheet. Therefore, as you pointed out, the reading on the multimeter will be higher. But what I don't get then, is why it would be unsafe? Isn't the voltage reading of 17-18 volts then somewhat artificial? How could it go above the 14.4 volt open circuit voltage? Thanks Andy.

Comment: It's unsafe because the meter says it's unsafe - 17 volts is well above the maximum recommended charging voltage for a lead acid battery and that's just the average voltage - it'll probably peak around 21 volts and is therefore dangerous to have this sort of voltage on a lead acid battery even if it's just a few milli seconds each cycle of AC.

Comment: The 14.4 volts reading is when the output is connected to nothing - look at the picture in my answer - 14.4 volts is at the average level shown. Divide this by 0.636 and you get a peak voltage of nearly 23 volts (that of course drops under load but probably only to 21 volts).

Comment: Andy, when I hookup a 25 watt 12v light bulb to the 14.4 volt output, the voltage drops to about 12.9... when I hookup a large motor which opens and closes my car door, the voltage drops. So, for everything other than the car battery, the open circuit voltage is higher, as expected. I don't think I'm out of bounds on this question, I really do just want to learn and understand what is happening. Thank you for taking this time.

Comment: Andy, your explanation of how it doesn't zero cross because of the battery makes sense, but it doesn't answer what the heart of my question is. How can I do damage to a battery when it's provided current to it from what is effectively a 14.4 volt and 12.5 volt sources that are in parallel?

Comment: The voltages shouldn't add together, because they are in parallel. It just doesn't make sense to me. So I should remove windings from the transformer till it reads maybe 10.5 volts open circuit? So the light bulb would now barely light up and read maybe 9 volts... all other inductive and resistive loads would drop the voltage below 10, but miraculously this will provide 14.4 volts to the battery?

Comment: It's fine for driving a twelve volt motor or lamp but not fine for charging a lead acid battery.

Comment: But why? I really do just want to understand this. Thanks again for the time you have spent on this question.

Comment: Why is it that 2 sources in parallel can provide a voltage with significant current behind it which is well above either of the 2 source's voltage??

Comment: The 1st source that you call 14.4 volts is in fact a voltage with an average level of 14.4 volts - it peaks up to 23 volts and drops down to zero - it has an average value of 14.4 volts - look at the picture in my answer (having said this a couple of times now) - 14.4 volts is the dotted line marked "average = 0.636 MAX". Tell me when you get this bit.

Comment: Ahhh. I think I get it now. Since the zero peaks (or valleys I guess) are now "filled in" by the batteries voltage, the presence of those 20+ volt spikes are now much more apparent. I was thinking you guys were somehow saying that the voltages added although they were in parallel. But you are saying that the higher voltage was always there, just that it was balanced out by the zero valleys. I REALLY appreciate the time you took for this. This is my first post so I'm not sure what I need to do now. I found this answer to be most helpful, though.

Comment: Appreciation is always more profoind when you formally accept an answer. There's a symbol near the top of all answers on the left.

Comment: Ok I accepted it. Thanks. Was I understanding it correctly from my last comment?

Comment: Yes you have got it

Answer (score 2):

Without a filter capacitor or battery, the output voltage from the bridge rectifier will dip to zero every half cycle, and your meter will read some sort of "average" value of that waveform.

When you add the battery, the voltage will only fall to the battery voltage, rather than to zero, every half cycle, so your meter will see a higher "average" voltage than without the battery.

Comment: I think this makes sense. Is it safe to charge the 12 volt battery, even though its giving a voltage reading much higher than the 14.4 max for charging a 12v lead acid? Thanks.

Comment: No - you shouldn't use this supply to charge a 12 volt lead-acid battery, as the peak voltage is much higher than the normal charge voltage of the battery.

Comment: Okay, but then I don't really get what is happening. The transformer shouldn't be capable of outputting more than 14.4 volts after rectification. 14.4 is an acceptable voltage to charge a 12v lead acid battery. Effectively, the transformers output is in parallel with the battery terminals, which is around 12.5 volts. Why would a 14.4 volt DC source, paralleled with a 12.5 volt DC source, be dangerous to charge a 12v lead acid battery with?

Answer (score 0):

There are some oversights in your assumptions. Perhaps mine too. Let's see.
I did some rough calcs and think your MOT should be **12Vac(rms)** for a 12V battery @14.2Vdc

I assume you are measuring Vac with a DMM that in AC measures Peak voltage and converts to RMS assuming a sine wave and in DC mode uses RC LPF and only measures Average DC voltage not peak.

Meanwhile you are not using a sine wave, but a rectified sine wave so your measurements are slightly wrong and there are conversion factors for this , like Pi/rt(2) but a scope is better.

What you need to understand is the actual Peak voltage of the sine which then becomes the battery voltage ( minus 2 diode drops)

For a 12V battery at 14.2V max assuming lead acid.

- assume Diode drop = 1.3 at low current. (for 2*0.65) and 2V max(2 * 1V @ xx Amps) at max current
- now you have 15.5V before diodes
- Assume transformer coupling loss is 10% ( due to load impedance of battery/Source impedance of transformer) so rated load voltage / no load AC voltage is 90% ( for typical designs more or less  but in MVA transformers loss ~1% not 10%!
- now you have 15.5V* (1+10%) = 17V
- then **take Vrms/Vp of 17V = .707 *17V = 12Vac (rms)** which is what your supply windings should generate at full load or 13.2Vac no load.

Compare my assumptions against yours.

Welcome to SE.EE

extra info

- average of a full wave rectified AC is ;

  - \$ V_{avg} = 2/\pi{} V_p\$
- while RMS of a sine wave

  - \$V_{rms}=1/\sqrt{2}V_p\$

Conclusion

Reduce turns ratio on MOT on secondary by 14.2/18 like 7/9 turns ratio = after/before in order to get 13V rising to 14.2 at full charge.

### so remove one winding turn, measure into a cap load only and adjust turns accordingly for 14.2Vdc or float charge of 13.8 on SLA ...n.b.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. What I don't get though is why the voltage goes down (as it should) for all other resistive and inductive loads that I have tried. Why does the voltage go way up when trying to charge the 12v lead acid?

Comment: I guess my main issue is that the open circuit voltage is LOWER than with a load, but only when connected to a battery. All other resistive and inductive loads, the voltage drops as expected.

Comment: a really big transformer in megaVolt-Amp ratings..No, your big issue is DC meter measures average not peak, while AC measures peak and converts to average or RMS which differ slightly.  The battery acts as peak and hold detector capacitor of >> 10k Farads then the amount of AC ripple on battery is a ratio of battery Voltage ESR to diode ESR during a narrow peak pulse charge current Ipk= avg discharge current/%ripple V on battery

Comment: . if you see twice the DC voltage on AC then /2 , this is peak DC voltage. and meter is not AC coupled rather DC coupled into a bridge

Comment: All of the measurments I provide are on the DC setting though. I am measuring the rectified voltage. I'm hung up on the fact that other resistive and inductive loads drop the voltage, but not when connected to a battery.

Comment: a diode is a nonlinear switch to an inductor and gives different V with a capacitor which will be same as a battery..you do not have a linear network.

Comment: did you try a Cap load? this will be exactly same as a fully charged battery and xcept lead acid max is 14.5 and drops near 12.6 with load and charge removed. this is 100% SoC while Near 0% SoC=11.5V with a 1 V range roughly so remove one winding turn, measure into a cap and adjust accordingly for 14.2 or float charge of 13.8 on SLA

Comment: Your suggested solution you provided in bold is exactly what I would do if I didn't have any resources like this forum to learn what was going on. I can make it work. I just want to understand why what is happening is happening. Thanks.

Comment: ok this teaches about measurement errors and ESR losses and peak voltage during low battery vs fully charge battery, where you can increase charge current with fatter diodes rated for 100A and higher turns ratio, then you need a relay with OVP sensing when current reduces to 10% of peak at CV of 14.2V or as in 3 phase alternators the control field current is reduced to regulate the voltage.